# Objects mismatch

Tags: python, json, class, encoding

I'm writing in python some json encoders for a dictionary derived class, the class EPPI_dictDB, the object of this class may be store as value some instances of the class parser.

BUT when I would encode something goes wrong and the instance of the class EPPI_dictDB passed to the specific encoder function becomes an instance of the class parser!

Let me explain better with an example.
If I execute this code

```
import json
import raw.data_input as data_input
p = data_input.parser()
class data():
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

data1 = data()
data1.name = "data1"
data1.proteins = ['acc1','acc2']
data1.peptides = [('acc1',['SEQTWO']),
                      ('acc2',['SEQONE'])]
p.parse(data1)
s = EPPI_dbopen('tmp.prj', flag='n')
s["parser"] = p

print s.__class__
print isinstance(s, EPPI_DictDB)
print isinstance(s, data_input.parser)
```

I obtain these results:

```
<class '__main__.EPPI_DictDB'>
True
False
```

after I call the encoder:

```
print json.dumps(obj=s, cls=projectEncoder)
```

Inside the code of the encode I put some 'prints' to determine the nature of the passed object:

```
class projectEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):

        print obj.__class__
        print isinstance(obj, EPPI_DictDB)
        print isinstance(obj, data_input.parser)

        if isinstance(obj, EPPI_DictDB):
            result = obj.__dict__
            if "parser" in result.keys():
                pars = result["parser"]
                result["parser"] = parserEncoder().encode(pars)
            if "selected" in results.keys():
                sel = result["selected"]
                result["selected"] = parserEncoder().encode(sel)
            return result
        return json.JSONEncoder.default(self, obj)
```

The results of inner prints are:

```
<class 'raw.data_input.parser'>
False
True
```

Could anyone explain me what happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing a bit:

JSON encoders already know how to handle dicts, so it treats your dict subclass the same way as a dict. However, when it reaches s["parser"], it doesn't know what to do with the object, so it calls your `default` method on it. I.e. from your code, it's seeing `p`, not `s`.

This seems to be what [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/json#json.JSONEncoder) say.

**EDIT**

Looking at what you're actually doing, I think there should be an easier way to achieve this:

```
def default(self, obj):
    if isinstance(obj, data_input.parser):
        return parserEncoder().encode(obj)
    return super(projectEncoder, self).default(obj)
```

If the `"selected"` field is another type, then just change the second line to:

```
if isinstance(obj, (data_input.parser, type_of_selected)):
```

Comment: The problem is not inside the encoders classes, but in the built-in `__dict__`. I made an experiment to determine this, I wrote functions for the conversion from  to dictionaries, obtaining the same results that I've posted. But I understand you, your message is clear, Thomas K, why I must convert to a dict a dict? The assumption is wrong!

Comment: @gunzapper: It does seem odd. But presumably if you're subclassing dict, you're using a mapping of some kind, and there's only one way to represent a mapping in JSON. In fact, looking at what you're doing, there should be an easier way to do this. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yesterday I chosen to follow a more simple way: register each param of parsers object inside EPPI_DictDB. I write also getty methods to obtain parsers objects back. It works. selected is a derivative class of parser. However, I think that it is a strange behavior. I'll try your solution also.